# Create a Map<String, Set<String>> from a List<MyObject> using Stream API

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have a list of `LoggerMessageDto` objects.

`LoggerMessageDto` has two `String` *fields:* `message` and `type`.

I want to convert this `List` into a `Map` with the following contents:

```
 key: "types",     value: Set.of(LoggerMessageDto::gettype) 
 key: "messages" , value: Set.of(LoggerMessageDto::getMessage)
```

*My attempt:*

```
List<LoggerMessageDto> result = getSomeResult();
Set<String> journalTypes = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> messages = new HashSet<>();

result.forEach(item -> {
    journalTypes.add(item.getType());
    messages.add(item.getMessage());
});

String typesKey = "types";
String messagesKey = "messages";

Map<String, Set<String>> map = Map.of(
    typesKey, journalTypes,
    messagesKey, messages
);
```

How can I achieve this using Stream API?

Comment: Your current code looks good. What benefit do you expect to get from using streams instead?

Comment: Besides using an `enum KeyEnum { TYPES, MESSAGES } and an EnumMap` it looks okay.

Comment: @BasilBourque solely for compactness, and for general study

Comment: @JoopEggen good point, thanks, added Enum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Java 12 - `Collectors.teeing`

You can use Java 12 *collector* [`teeing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)), which expects *three arguments*: two *collectors* and a *function*. Each stream element gets consumed by both of the provided *collectors* and when they are done the *function* merges their results.

As both *downstream collectors* of `teeing` we can use *collector* [`mapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) in conjunction with the *collector* `toSet()`.

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> toMessagesByType(List<LoggerMessageDto> loggerMessageList,
                                                        String typesKey,
                                                        String messagesKey) {
    return  loggerMessageList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.teeing(
            Collectors.mapping(LoggerMessageDto::getType, Collectors.toSet()),
            Collectors.mapping(LoggerMessageDto::getMessage, Collectors.toSet()),
            (types, messages) -> Map.of(
                typesKey, types,
                messagesKey, messages
            )
        ));
}
```

## Java 8 - String Keys

Here's a Java 8 compliant code which makes use of *three-argument* version of [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) and produces the same result as solution with `teeing()`:

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> toMessagesByType(List<LoggerMessageDto> loggerMessageList,
                                                        String typesKey,
                                                        String messagesKey) {
    return loggerMessageList.stream()
        .collect(
            () -> Map.of(
                typesKey, new HashSet<>(),
                messagesKey,  new HashSet<>()
            ),
            (Map<String, Set<String>> map, LoggerMessageDto next) -> {
                map.get(typesKey).add(next.getType());
                map.get(messagesKey).add(next.getMessage());
            },
            (left, right) ->
                right.forEach((k, v) -> left.get(k).addAll(v))
        );
}
```

## Enum

Also, it's worth to mention that *enums* are more handy and reliable than strings, as *@Joop Eggen* has point out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73530811/how-can-i-create-a-mapstring-setstring-from-listobject-use-stream-api-jav/73531066#comment129848630_73530811). Apart from saving you from typo which might occur while using strings, *enums* have an extensive language support (specialized collections: `EnumMap`, `EnumSet`; they can be used in custom annotations; and in `switch` expression/statements, etc.).

## Java 8 - Enum & EnumMap

Similarly to the solution shown above, we can use of *three-args* `collect()` and provide a prepopulated `EnumMap` in the *supplier*.

```
public static Map<LoggerKeys, Set<String>> toMessagesByType(List<LoggerMessageDto> loggerMessageList) {
    
    return loggerMessageList.stream()
        .collect(
            () -> EnumSet.allOf(LoggerKeys.class).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Function.identity(),
                    e -> new HashSet<>(),
                    (v1, v2) -> { throw new AssertionError("duplicates are not expected"); },
                    () -> new EnumMap<>(LoggerKeys.class)
                )),
            (Map<LoggerKey, Set<String>> map, LoggerMessageDto next) ->
                map.forEach((loggerKey, set) -> set.add(loggerKey.getKey(next))),
            (left, right) ->
                right.forEach((k, v) -> left.get(k).addAll(v))
        );
}
```

`LoggerKey` *enum* having a *keyExtractor* `Function` as a property:

```
public enum LoggerKey {
    TYPES(LoggerMessageDto::getType), MESSAGES(LoggerMessageDto::getMessage);
    
    private Function<LoggerMessageDto, String> keyExtractor;

    LoggerKeys(Function<LoggerMessageDto, String> keyExtractor) {
        this.keyExtractor = keyExtractor;
    }

    public Function<LoggerMessageDto, String> getKey(LoggerMessageDto dto) {
        return keyExtractor.apply(dto);
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I'm using java 11, is there any similar solution?

Comment: @AlekseyBakharev You should put such constraints into your Question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Ivanchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73531066/642706) is correct and quite clever. But that solution requires Java 12+, and [you later commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73530811/create-a-mapstring-setstring-from-a-listmyobject-using-stream-api/73537637#comment129858692_73531066) that you must use Java 11.

## `list.stream().map( getter ).collect( …`

Here is another solution, this one working in Java 11.

Here we run through the list twice. On the first run, we use the getter method `type` to extract the `type` member field on the `Log` class. We collect those strings into a `Set`. Then we make a second run through the `List` of `Log` objects, this time extracting the `message` member field by calling the getter `message`. Those strings are also collected into a `Set`.

We put each of the two sets into a `Map`.

```java
Map < String, Set < String > > map =
        Map.of(
                "types" , list.stream().map( Log :: type ).collect( Collectors.toSet() ) ,
                "messages" , list.stream().map( Log :: message ).collect( Collectors.toSet() )
        );
```

Caveat: This approach is a little bit inefficient in that it loops the list twice, once for "types" and once for "messages". But unless you are doing this many times for huge amounts of data, the impact on performance should be insignificant.

Generally best to work with unmodifiable collections until you know otherwise.  So let's make those [sets unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable). The `Map.of` is already producing an [unmodifiable `Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) object.

```java
Map < String, Set < String > > map =
        Map.of(
                "types" , list.stream().map( Log :: type ).collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet() ) ,
                "messages" , list.stream().map( Log :: message ).collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet() )
        );
```

Here is a complete example. For brevity I used the [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) feature in Java 16+, but you could just as well define a conventional class. By the way, note that in Java 16+, records, enums, and interfaces can all be declared locally.

```java
record Log( String type , String message ) { }
List < Log > list =
        List.of(
                new Log( "INFO" , "dog" ) ,
                new Log( "ERROR" , "dog" ) ,
                new Log( "INFO" , "cat" ) ,
                new Log( "INFO" , "cat" ) ,
                new Log( "DEBUG" , "cat" )
        );

Map < String, Set < String > > map =
        Map.of(
                "types" , list.stream().map( Log :: type ).collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet() ) ,
                "messages" , list.stream().map( Log :: message ).collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet() )
        );

System.out.println( "map = " + map );
```

> map = {types=[INFO, DEBUG, ERROR], messages=[cat, dog]}

By the way, be aware that `Set` and `Map` by definition may **iterate in any arbitrary order**. The order may change even between two iterations done one after another. If order matters to you, use a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) implementation and a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) implementation.